In Rust Axum I want my router handler receive several headers. Can I receive these header as a struct, that contais the fields I'm expecting?
I expect receive these headers on a GET request:
Y-VERSION
Z-TYPE
Z-SESSION
Can I receive them in a struct like this?
pub struct CustomHeaders {
    #[serde(rename = "Y-VERSION")]
    pub version: String,
    #[serde(rename = "Z-TYPE")]
    pub type: String,
    #[serde(rename = "Z-SESSION")]
    pub session: String
}

I tried using TypedHeader, but it seems not what I'm expecting because I need custom headers.
I expect something like the axum::extract::Query
Example:
pub async fn find_balance(
Path(account_string): Path<String>,
query_params: Query<QueryParams>, 

This is the signature of the function I'm using with HeaderMap by now to extract only the Authorization header:
#[debug_handler]
pub async fn find_balance(
    Path(balance_string): Path<String>,
    query_params: Query<QueryParams>,
    header_map: HeaderMap,
    JwtClaims(user): JwtClaims<RegisteredClaims>,
    State(client): State<Client>
) -> Result<Json<BalanceDTO>, Error> {
    let token = header_map.get(String::from("Authorization")).unwrap().to_str().unwrap();
    ...


If possible I would like an example of using TypedHeader please.
Thanks in advance!

TypedHeader is the correct way. Can you share the code that didn't work?

Hi Friedman!
I posted the function signature in the question.
Could you provide an example please?
Thanks in advance!

Please edit it into the question. Also, not only the signature.

You can do it with TypedHeader (in axum-extra, no longer in axum). Since you have three headers, it will be nice to use a macro to create them, and you can group them together with #[derive(FromRequestParts)]:
use axum::extract::FromRequestParts;
use axum::http::{HeaderName, HeaderValue};
use axum_extra::headers::{self, Header};
use axum_extra::TypedHeader;

macro_rules! declare_header {
    ( $name:expr => $struct:ident ) => {
        pub struct $struct(pub String);

        impl Header for $struct {
            fn name() -> &'static HeaderName {
                static NAME: HeaderName = HeaderName::from_static($name);
                &NAME
            }

            fn decode<'i, I>(values: &mut I) -> Result<Self, headers::Error>
            where
                Self: Sized,
                I: Iterator<Item = &'i HeaderValue>,
            {
                let value = values.next().ok_or_else(headers::Error::invalid)?;
                value
                    .to_str()
                    .map_err(|_| headers::Error::invalid())
                    .map(|value| Self(value.to_owned()))
            }

            fn encode<E: Extend<HeaderValue>>(&self, values: &mut E) {
                values.extend(std::iter::once(
                    HeaderValue::from_str(&self.0).expect("invalid header value"),
                ));
            }
        }
    };
}

declare_header!("y-version" => YVersion);
declare_header!("z-type" => ZType);
declare_header!("z-session" => ZSession);

#[derive(FromRequestParts)]
struct CustomHeaders {
    #[from_request(via(TypedHeader))]
    pub version: YVersion,
    #[from_request(via(TypedHeader))]
    pub r#type: ZType,
    #[from_request(via(TypedHeader))]
    pub session: ZSession,
}

Then use CustomHeaders as a normal extractor (parameter to your handler).
